# Columns in data.frame appear empty when using head(data.frame), but when using levels(data.frame$column1) appear to have values

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that includes names of sites, their latitude, and the longitude, among other data. When I write `head(data.frame)`, the column with the site names looks correct, but the latitude and longitude columns are empty (there are no values at all in them). However, when I write `levels(data.frame$longitude)`, all of the values for the longitudes of my site appear. The same issue is occurring with latitude.

I am wondering why these values don't appear when I look up the head of the `data.frame`, but do appear when I look up the level?

Many thanks!

Comment: head() only shows the first few lines of a data.frame. Have you checked whether the whole column is empty? Or are there any NAs?

Comment: There aren't any NAs. I checked tail() as well and I get the same result - it indicates the last few rows of latitude and  longitude are empty as well

Comment: Have you just checked tail() or have you done sum(is.na(data.frame$lat) etc..? Maybe there is a level which is just a "blank"? It is possible btw for a factor object to have levels, that actually don't exist anymore in the object. You get rid of them using `droplevels(data.frame)`.

Answer (score 0):

`levels()` returns the levels associated with a factor.  Not all values need to exist.  For example, if you do

```
x <- factor(letters)
x[1:3]
```

you'll see

```
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

because all 26 levels are still associated with the factor, even though only 3 of them are observed.

In your case, it's possible that one of the levels of your factor is a blank string.  You can get this using

```
x <- factor("", levels = c("", letters))
```

or by reading in data containing blanks in some columns.

To find out all the values in a column, don't use `levels(x)`, use `unique(x)`.  That will still show all levels if `x` is a factor, but it will also show which values actually occur in the column.